# Не получается создать фрагмент в фрагменте

Tags: android

нужна помощь с добавлением таблицы, как фрагмент на лэйаут другого фрагмента. Когда я запускаю приложение, происходит вылет, при переходе на фрагмент с другим фрагментом.

Лэйаут с таблицей:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableRow android:background="#cccccc"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Дата"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                />
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Кол-во"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                />
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Сумма"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:padding="5dp">
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2012-11-22"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                />
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="397"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                />
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="19039.21"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:padding="5dp">
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2012-11-23"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                />
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="348"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                />
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="16759.28"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:padding="5dp">
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2012-11-24"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                />
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="305"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                />
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="14527.19"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Код фрагмента с таблицей:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class table extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment7, null);
    }
}
```

Код фрагмента в котором надо создать фрагмент с таблицей:

```
public class fragment5 extends Fragment {

    table table;
    FragmentTransaction fTrans;
    CheckBox chbStack;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment5, null);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        table = new table();

        fTrans.add(R.id.frgmCont2, table);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fTrans.commit();
    }

}
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer, PID: 22035
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.app.FragmentTransaction
>   android.app.FragmentTransaction.add(int, android.app.Fragment)' on a
>   null object reference                                     at
>   com.example.jone1.graciaonline.fragment5.onViewCreated(fragment5.java:53)
>   at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1010)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
>                                                                                                at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:816)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1580)
>                                                                                                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)

Answer (score 0):

у вас нарушен алгоритм. При создании View вы добавляете в "стек" фрагмент
`fTrans.add(R.id.frgmCont2, table);`, а потом, при клике на кнопку переинициализируете фрагмент менеджер: `fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();` Делайте все в одном месте, локально. не храните менеджер в глобальной переменной и будет вам щастье

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить в layout фрагмента (в который нужно вставить другой фрагмент) объект FrameLayout, и потом с помощью FragmentTransaction переместить фрагмент с таблицей в FrameLayout в другом фрагменте. Должно получится что-то вроде этого:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.idFrameLayout, new YoursFragmentName());
ft.setTransition(FragmentTrasaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

(В моём коде могут быть небольшие помарки, но в целом, я думаю, что он должен помочь)